# reading messages from MQ using java

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler, mq

I need some design and developments inputs on reading messages from queue. i have following requirements and constraints

1. i need read message from queue and inert to db.
2. messages can come at any interval (100's at same time or 1 by one with few mins gap)
3. don't have any MDB container to host (just plain tomcat server)
4. Need to write java application to perform the above.

so not very sure how to put this simple application.

1. if is use quartz scheduler to trigger job to read all messages in the queue then not sure before even that complete next instance of scheduler might start and create problem.

please suggest me any inputs.

this is basically some utility so i don't want to spend too long time nor too much resources on this.

thanks & regards

LR

Comment: this is basically a question "please think this for me, since I don't feel like doing that" so I don't want to spend too long time nor too much resources answering this.

Comment: did your queue deployed in tomcat ? JMS listener and startup servlet would work .

Answer (score 0):

The usage of an ESB like Mule or Camel would simplify a lot your development. You'd find already developed components (called endpoints) for reading from a queue, and writing into a db. Also for scheduling jobs with quartz.

Comment: Thank you, as said in my requirement, this is utility so don't want use another S/W and maintenance so want to implement this with java and running on existing utility server tomcat.

Comment: You can use Mule or Camel and deploy it on Tomcat. I think that for this particular app the advantages of using an ESB would be huge.